# Alter Table Depending on Multiple Columns

Tags: db2, alter

I have a table that has categories like `ID`, a `category`, `type`, `date` and `Shop`. I want to create a new table where I drop the `type` column. If `ID`, `Category`, `Date` and `Shop` are the same then I drop the multiple rows and just keep one row and add a count of how many items they have bought. And if `ID`, `category`, `date` and `shop` are the same, but `category` isn't, the `category` becomes Fruit/Veg and the count is added with the number of items bought. I've highlighted what my current table looks like and what the new table will look like. But I'm not sure how to go about creating this new table.

I've started with

```sql
CREATE TABLE SINGLE_ROW AS
SELECT ID, Category, Date, Shop
FROM customer_items
```

But I'm not sure how to alter the table to what I need.

| ID | Category | Type | Date | Shop |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Fruit | Apple | 1/2/23 | Shop3 |
| 1 | Fruit | Banana | 1/2/23 | Shop3 |
| 1 | Fruit | Strawberry | 4/2/23 | Shop3 |
| 2 | Fruit | Apple | 15/2/23 | Shop1 |
| 2 | Veg | Carrot | 15/2/23 | Shop1 |
| 3 | Fruit | Banana | 14/6/23 | Shop5 |
| 3 | Fruit | Banana | 14/6/23 | Shop10 |

| ID | Category | Date | Shop | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Fruit | 1/2/23 | Shop3 | 2 |
| 1 | Fruit | 4/2/23 | Shop3 | 1 |
| 2 | Fruit/Veg | 15/2/23 | Shop1 | 2 |
| 3 | Fruit | 14/6/23 | Shop5 | 1 |
| 3 | Fruit | 14/6/23 | Shop10 | 1 |

Comment: mysql and db2 are two very different database products. Which one do you use? Do you truly want to create a new table or do you just want to produce an new output like you described using a select statement?

Comment: If you want to solve this in SQL alone, then you should look into GROUP BY and aggregate functions first of all.

Comment: @Shadow Sorry about that, I'm using DB2. I need this to be a new table because I have to give it to someone else to use and do analysis on.

Answer (score 0):

You may use so called `REFRESH DEFERRED` MQT.
Just run the `REFRESH TABLE` statement when you have finished with editing `customer_items` to make Db2 automatically recalculate the `SINGLE_ROW` table with agg results based on the query in its definition.
You may create index(es) to speedup user queries on `SINGLE_ROW` as well if needed.

```
CREATE TABLE customer_items AS 
(
SELECT *
FROM
(
VALUES 
  (1, 'Fruit', 'Apple     ', '1/2/23 ', 'Shop3 ')
, (1, 'Fruit', 'Banana    ', '1/2/23 ', 'Shop3 ')
, (1, 'Fruit', 'Strawberry', '4/2/23 ', 'Shop3 ')
, (2, 'Fruit', 'Apple     ', '15/2/23', 'Shop1 ')
, (2, 'Veg  ', 'Carrot    ', '15/2/23', 'Shop1 ')
, (3, 'Fruit', 'Banana    ', '14/6/23', 'Shop5 ')
, (3, 'Fruit', 'Banana    ', '14/6/23', 'Shop10')
) T (ID, Category, Type, Date, Shop)
) WITH DATA
```

```
CREATE TABLE SINGLE_ROW AS
(
SELECT 
    ID
  , LISTAGG (DISTINCT Category, '/') AS CATEGORY
  , Date
  , Shop
  , COUNT (1) AS COUNT
FROM customer_items
GROUP BY ID, Date, Shop
) DATA INITIALLY DEFERRED REFRESH DEFERRED
```

```
REFRESH TABLE SINGLE_ROW
```

```
SELECT * FROM SINGLE_ROW
```

| ID | CATEGORY | DATE | SHOP | COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Fruit | 1/2/23 | Shop3 | 2 |
| 1 | Fruit | 4/2/23 | Shop3 | 1 |
| 2 | Fruit/Veg | 15/2/23 | Shop1 | 2 |
| 3 | Fruit | 14/6/23 | Shop10 | 1 |
| 3 | Fruit | 14/6/23 | Shop5 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6rv0qDZt)